# Toggle jQuery.remove()

Tags: jquery, accessibility, screen-readers

Instead of .show()'ing and .hide()'ing (or .toggle()'ing for that matter), is there any way to "toggle" a .remove() function?

I realize .remove() literally removes elements from the DOM, so it sounds difficult to magically replace the removed elements once they're gone, but is there a way of faking it?

Note: They must be removed from the DOM so that they are ignored by screen readers (AFAIK screen readers do not respect .show() and .hide()).

Thanks.

**--- EDIT ---**

OK, so .detach() might work for me. If my markup is:

```
<a href="#">Toggle images</a>

<p><span>Some text here</span><img src='image1.png'/><img src='image2.png'/></p>
<p><span>Some more text</span><img src='image2.png'/></p>
<p><span>Even more text</span><img src='image5.png'/><img src='image1.png'/>
  <img src='image5.png'/></p>
```

And by clicking the anchor it would remove all images, and clicking again would restore. Using .detach() how would it work?

**--- EDIT #2 ---**

As thenduks pointed out, screen readers in fact *do* respect `display: none;` which changes my question a bit. I ended up with a simple toggle code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could try using jQuery 1.4's recent addition: [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove them and then re-add them later.

Comment: Yea pretty handy. I had some sorting code on a side project that was sped up immensely after jQuery 1.4 came out and I started using this.

Comment: .detach() would work. I updated my question slightly, since I've never used it before and the API sample only confused me :)

Comment: You'll meet the same changes as you would with `.remove()`. The only difference between the two is that `detach()` retains data like event handlers. OP was concerned with how to easily re-insert back into the original position.

Comment: If you want to put them back in the original position then I fail to see why you wouldn't just hide them and not remove them in the first place.

Comment: @thenduks - Take another look at the question: *"Note: They must be removed from the DOM so that they are ignored by screen readers (AFAIK screen readers do not respect .show() and .hide())."* I don't know if that's correct about screen readers, but this was OPs reason for this approach.

Comment: Screen readers normally wont execute much javascript at all. Also, in my experience screen readers _do_ ignore elements that are hidden (display: none).

Comment: It's not true that they don't respect javascript at all -- depending on the screen reader, they actually do. It is true, in fact, that they respect `display: none;` -- Therefore the scope of my question changes and I can simply use `.toggle()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the DOM element(s) to a variable to be added back again later.

Check example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FrbBd/3/).

Comment: there's a great chance that `$('p').remove();` will return null so I don't think `savedNodes = $('p').remove();` would work but that's the right idea